# Github desktop open in sublime, not atom

Tags: sublimetext, atom-editor, github-desktop

In GitHub Desktop, is there any way to change the right click "Open in Atom" option, to instead be "Open in Sublime" or some other text editor?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Until they allow that, I'm doing `cmd+T`, then I type in `subl .` — This opens Sublime Text in the current folder if you [have `subl` defined](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## New answer for GitHub Desktop (Electron)

They finally added an option in the Preferences:

[image: preferences]

## Old answer for GitHub App Classic (Native)

GitHub looks for `/Applications/Atom.app` when clicking on "Open in Atom", so you just need to rename your editor to `Atom.app`, or...

Create a dummy app that opens Sublime. You can download [the app](https://github.com/bfred-it/github-desktop-open-in-sublime-text) that I made with Automator or make one yourself:

1. In Automator, select **Application**
2. Add the action **Run Shell Script**
3. Select **As arguments** in the **Pass input** dropdown
4. Enter this: `/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl "$@"`
5. Save it as **Atom** in the **Applications** folder.

[image: Expected Automator file]

Now "Open in Atom" should simply "Open in Sublime Text"

Comment: Oh my... so easy!  The App icon needs to be changed too, but that's optional.  Also harder.

Comment: Change Icon, see [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/369/can-i-change-the-application-icon-of-an-automator-script#answer-370) and refresh app icon in Launchpad & Doc, see [here](https://gist.github.com/fabiofl/5873100#gistcomment-1406760)

Comment: Okay. This is great. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This also works if you are using Visual Studio Code. Just change to the following -- `/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code\ -\ Insiders.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron "$@"` (modify to point to your VSS app).

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as it seems to be a part of app's menu.
However, you can set your default editor in `global config` like

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

For more, refer [Associating text editors with Git](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/)

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea. I tried following the instructions on the page you linked to: `git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"`, restarted github desktop, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

## on Windows with portable Sublime Text editor.

You need to create a registry key with a path to a folder where **subl.exe** file is.
This is the absolute minimum (of valunames) for the key:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Sublime Text 3_is1]
"Publisher"="Sublime HQ Pty Ltd"
"DisplayName"="Sublime Text 3"
"InstallLocation"="C:\\Apps\\YOUR\\PATH\\TO\\Sublime\\"
"Comment"="This key is needed for Github to detect SublimeText"
```

valuename `Comment` is not needed. I added it for myself to remember what's this key about.

This is the registry location for Uninstall info. But because I removed most of the valuenames which original Sublime installation creates, Windows Uninstall will not show this as an entry to remove in Uninstall.

Comment: This answer is incredibly useful for adding your own entries to the menu even when using portable apps. You can find the other natively supported options and their required registry key names by browsing the source file here https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/development/app/src/lib/editors/win32.ts